# How to write value in text file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm working on a number of views per page using JavaScript.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
       var cookiec = document.cookie
       if (cookiec != "") {
               var eqchr = 0;
               for (var cloop = 1; cloop <= cookiec.length; cloop++) {
                       if (cookiec.charAt(cloop) == "=") {
                               eqchr=(++cloop);
                       }
               }
               var cookiess = 0;
               clength=cookiec.length;
               cookies="";
               for (cloop = eqchr; cloop < clength; cloop++) {
                       if (cookiec==";") {
                               cloop=clength;
                       }
                       else {
                               cookies = cookies + cookiec.charAt(cloop);                        
                       }
               }
               cookiess = parseInt(cookies);
               document.write("[" + cookiess + "]");
               cookiess++;
               cookies = cookiess;
               var one_week = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
               var expDate = new Date();
               expDate.setTime(expDate.getTime() + one_week);
               document.cookie = "Counter=" + escape(cookies) + "; expires=" + expDate.toGMTString();
       }        
       else {
               var one_week = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
               var expDate = new Date();
               expDate.setTime(expDate.getTime() + one_week);
                document.cookie = "Counter=2; expires=" + expDate.toGMTString();
               document.write("[1]");
       }
       
// -->
</SCRIPT>
```

I am using the above JavaScript to calculate the number of views per page and I want to write the data in a text file.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Snakes and Coffee asked you a question: are you open to using a library to simplify your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your JavaScript is running in a browser environment, I would highly recommend either using [HTML5 localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) for storing (key, value) pairs or using [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to communicate with a server instead of trying to access a file on the client machine which may potentially become a security/privacy issue. Below is a simple example of using `localStorage` to store a page view count:

```
if (localStorage.numberOfViews) {
  localStorage.numberOfViews = Number(localStorage.numberOfViews) + 1;
} else {
  localStorage.numberOfViews = 1;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: (Hint:  `localStorage.numberOfViews = +localStorage.numberOfViews + 1;` is a cleaner way of writing that.)

Comment: I like `parseInt(localStorage.numberOfViews, 10) + 1` better. The unary plus operator fails to pass through JSLint and is confusing to beginner JavaScript developers.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript, running in a normal web browser, has very very limited access to the local file system.

So modern web browsers will let you save data to a file in a specialized directory, isolated from everything else.

For the most part, using localStorage (as mentioned by the others), is your best bet.

If you are running under Windows you can create a specialized file called an '.HTA' which runs with the same kind of access and permissions that regular files use.

Answer (score 1):

Attribute  LANGUAGE="JavaScript" is deprecated. You can remove it.
Now, replying your question, you can do it with PHP. Send the data when the user enter the page,  send it via AJAX to your server and proccess it with PHP.